# How to combine policy in S3 using java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3

How to combine policy in S3 using java?

```
Statement allowRestrictedWriteStatement = new Statement(Effect.Allow)
        .withPrincipals(new Principal("1234567"))
        .withActions(S3Actions.DeleteObject)
        .withResources(new S3ObjectResource(myBucketName, "demoFolder1"));


Statement allowRestrictedWriteStatement2 = new Statement(Effect.Deny)
        .withPrincipals(new Principal("1234567"))
        .withActions(S3Actions.DeleteObject)
        .withResources(new S3ObjectResource(myBucketName, "demoFolder2"));

Policy policy2 = new Policy()
        .withStatements(allowRestrictedWriteStatement2)
        .withStatements(allowRestrictedWriteStatement);
```

It is setting only `allowRestrictedWriteStatement` statement or whoever comes last in `Policy` object(in our case `allowRestrictedWriteStatement`). Is there a way to combine both policy or multiple policy using one `Policy` object, please suggest any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `withStatements` once and pass multiple `Statement` instances ([JavaDoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/policy/Policy.html#withStatements-com.amazonaws.auth.policy.Statement...-)):

```
new Policy().withStatements(allowRestrictedWriteStatement, allowRestrictedWriteStatement2);
```